# remove " " after <div class="content">

Tags: nodes

On every content page of my drupal site, there is always a line with empty quotes " " after 
`<div class="content">`.
This happens only with the content page and not in any view page.
Can someone guide me how to delete this empty quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this is present in the output HTML, and not added by the browser or some JS library? A suitable way to test would be to retrieve the content page using `curl` or `wget` -

```
curl http://example.org/node/123 | grep 'div class="content'
```

- If the empty quotes are not present in the original HTML (as displayed by the above command), then you should check if the quotes are present in *all browsers*, or only *one browser*. It may relate to a JS library you're including, or to a browser plugin, or even just to your browser's means of displaying your sourcecode.
- If the empty quotes are present in the output from this command, then you can look towards some theme or module on your site. You could do this by switching themes first (to see if it's the current theme), then by disabling modules in turn (to see which specific module is causing it).

This is really just general debugging advice - you may need either to give more detail (eg the URL of your site), or investigate debugging techniques to trace the issue.

Comment: Thanks
The code didn't return me any html, so I'll try finding out if any module or js is causing this problem

Comment: You need to swap in a URL of your own in the above command. I've modified it to match 'div class="content clearfix some-other-class"' above, also. If possible, providing the URL of your affected site would probably help someone spot the issue.